# JQuery conflict not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to avoid the conflict between the jquery 1.2.6 and latest version 1.11.3, boostrap.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/custom.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
    var autocm = jQuery.noConflict();
    autocm("#search").autocomplete("php/getvalues.php", {
        width: 383,
        matchContains: true,
        //mustMatch: false,
        //minChars: 0,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: true,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: false
    });(autocm);
});
</script>



    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/carousel.js"></script>
 $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

        //Handles the carousel thumbnails
        $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
                var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
                var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length-1);
                var id = parseInt(id);
                $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
        });


        // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
        $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
                var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
                $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
        });
```

If I enable

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/carousel.js"></script>
```

The autocomplete won't work.

Comment: The bigger question is: Why are you trying to continue to use a version of jQuery that's been obsolete for **several years** in addition to something more current?

Comment: `autocm("#search").autocomplete("php/getvalues.php", {/*...*/});(autocm);` That bit at the end is a complete no-op. Which is a bit suspicious.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder..Thanks a lot buddy ... you just opened my eyes... got it working... :)

Answer (score 1):

> the autocomplete won't work

My guess — and it has to be a guess, as you haven't told us anything about the autocomplete — is that it uses something from jQuery 1.2.6 that is no longer present, or perhaps just not quite the same, as in jQuery 1.11.3. All that the `noConflict` call you're doing does is protect **your code** within that `ready` callback; any code in the autocompleter that uses either `$` or `jQuery` to access jQuery later, when the user does something, will be using v1.11.3.

The best course of action here is to not try to use two versions of jQuery in the same page. Very, very, very much second-best would be to edit the autocomplete to grab a local reference to the `jQuery` that's in effect as of when it **loads**, and continue to use that. (A well-written plugin would do that, but there are a lot of not-very-well-written plugins out there...)

That might be as simple as putting this at the beginning of the `js/custom.js` file:

```
(function($) {
    var jQuery = $;
```

...and this at the end of it:

```
})(jQuery);
```

But again, that's a very distant second-best solution. The best thing to do is not use jQuery 1.2.6. At all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have done.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var autocm = jQuery.noConflict();
autocm().ready(function() {
    autocm("#search").autocomplete("php/getvalues.php", {
        width: 383,
        matchContains: true,
        //mustMatch: false,
        //minChars: 0,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: true,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: false
    });
});(autocm);
</script>
```

Working well enough.. just added no conflict method before the .ready(function(){

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference at all.